# How to hide the existing data and display the Error message

Tags: angularjs

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="myCtrl.selectedEnvironment" 
ng-change="myCtrl.fetchEnvData(myCtrl.selectedEnvironment)"
ng-options="option.id as option.displayName for option in myCtrl.environments">     
</select>
```

if the selected option does not contain any data then i need to display error message instead of displaying existing data.

Data through server

```
fetchEnvData: function(envId) {
            console.log('http://......../'+envId);
                return $http.get('http://........../'+envId)
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                    return response.data;
                                },
                                function(errResponse){
                                    console.error('Error while fetching fetchEnvData');
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        }


controller code :

self.fetchEnvData = function(envId){
          EnvDataViewerService.fetchEnvData(envId)
              .then(
                           function(d) {
                                self.envData = d;
                           },
                            function(errResponse){
                                console.error('Error while fetching EnvData');
                                alert('Error While Fetching EnvData');
                            }
                   );
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
<div ng-if="myCtrl.selectedEnvironment">
  your display data here...
</div>
<div ng-if="!myCtrl.selectedEnvironment">
  {{message}}
</div>
```